# How to create a table from a list of tuples?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two lists:

```
students = ['A', 'B', 'C']
marks = [45, 78, 12]
```

I need to sort the `students` list based on the `marks` and display the output in a specific manner.

```
students = ['student1', 'student2', 'student3']
marks = [45, 78, 12]  #, 14, 48,]
sortedlist = sorted(zip(marks, students), reverse=True)
print(sortedlist)
```

I am getting the output as:

```
[(78, 'student2'), (45, 'student1'), (12, 'student3')]
```

I want the output as:

[image: a 2D table with first column student and the second column marks]

Is it possible to achieve? Also in the output, I need only two highest numbers and not all elements in the zipped list.

Comment: It's not clear what you want. Do you you just want the tuples reversed, or do you want a string: `student2 78 student1 45 student3 12`? Or a list of three strings?

Comment: I want the output as shown in the image..like a 2D table. First column will have student name and the second column will have marks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply format the `print`ing but only for the `n=2` first elements:

```py
for mark, name in sortedlist[:n]:
    print(name, '\t', mark)

# one-liner: print('\n'.join(name + '\t' + str(mark) for mark, name in sortedlist[:n]))
```

And this prints:

```
student2    78
student1    45
```